# Display accuracy circle with MapBox Android SDK

Tags: android, gps, mapbox

I'm working with MapBox SDK for an Android app.

I searched but didn't find the way to display accuracy circle around the current GPS position.

Do I have to draw it manually with "addpolygon" function?

Thank you for your help

Here is some code I use to display location on MapBox after "OnMapReady" function:

```
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    last_location = location;
                }
            }
        };

locationServices.addLocationListener(locationListener);
my_mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: the accuracy is automatically draw if you hook into using MyLocationView. How are you currently displaying the GPS position?

Comment: I used this tuto to display gps position: https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/user-location/ 
I'm gonna update my post to put the main functions I use.